# typescript function typing best practices and distinctions

Tags: typescript

Is there any difference in the typings below? or are they both the same and personal preference?

```js
interface ThingA{
  myFunc(): number;
}

interface ThingB{
 myFunc: () => number;
}
```

Comment: The most important difference is contravariance with function properties.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's just syntax sugar. Both means the same